# WP7 Silverlight class library localization

Tags: windows-phone-7, dll, localization

I am creating a WP7 silverlight class libary project which supports localization (English & German).I am keeping all the resources inside the class library itself.  The language changes were reflected correctly only when I run the application (Adding project reference) using this library from the same solution.

But when I use the library(.dll) in another solution the localization doesnt seem to work. Any ideas How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The other solution is a WP7, WP7.1 or WP8 solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to define the supported languages in your main project. For windows Phone 8 you can do this in the project properties. For windows phone 7 you need to change the project file manually using a text editor.